# How is a Spherical Harmonics Lightmap generated?

Tags: graphics, lightmap, spherical-harmonics

I have successfully generated a single color lightmap using ray tracing.
For each texel in the lightmap, I trace into the hemisphere (using the normal) and capture the incoming light.
This single color lightmap can't take normal mapping into account.

I have found [this site](https://andrew-pham.blog/2019/08/26/spherical-harmonics/) for an explanation how SH are generated but I have a question regarding that.

In a code listing, the author does this:

```
SH9Color genLightingCoefficientsForNormal(const glm::vec3& N, const glm::vec3& L)
{
    SH9 SHCoefficients = genSHCoefficients(N);
    SH9Color result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result._coefficients.size(); ++i)
    {
        result[i] = L * SHCoefficients[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am confused what the `SH9Color` contains. My assumption is that `SH9Color`itself is just a `float3[9]`. I.e. an array of colors.
But since it's an array of colors, how would that be stored in a texture? I would need 9 RGB textures to represent that. Thats a lot of space opposed to what I assumed to be only 3 (9 coefficients)

How are Spherical Harmonics Textures actually generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you linked isn't generating a lightmap, but a light *probe*. As they say in the Future Work section:

> The next thing I’d like to do is take this spherical harmonic concept and use it to implement **light probes** distributed in my scene. I’m curious to see how it all looks because, for now, the comparisons in the last section were made using a **single light probe** at the center of the scene (i.e., we generated maps with respect to world space location [0, 0, 0]).

When rendering with light probes, we generally have a sparse graph of sample points  in our scene for which we've calculated spherical harmonics coefficients, and we interpolate between them.

Because each probe is responsible for encoding the way light hits different surfaces over a wide area, we need a lot of coefficients to accurately encode that info. But since our probe graph is reasonably sparse, we don't mind storing too many coefficients, because we only need to store them for a "small" number of probes.

The situation with lightmaps is somewhat the opposite: we have a *dense* grid of samples, often every half or quarter meter along every surface in the scene. But because they're so tightly spaced, each sample doesn't need to store quite as much subtlety about the variation in light at that spot: that can come through in the differences in light captured at adjacent sample points. So we can afford to discard some of the higher-order coefficients without too noticeable a loss of fidelity.

[This GDC presentation about the use of spherical harmonics lightmaps in Star Wars Battlefront II](https://media.contentapi.ea.com/content/dam/eacom/frostbite/files/gdc2018-precomputedgiobalilluminationinfrostbite.pdf) shows they used only the first four coefficients for each of R, G, and B, or 12 values in all, compared to 27 if using all nine coefficients from the sample in the question.

They stored the L0 (average illumination) coefficients in the RGB channels of one high dynamic range texture. Then the L1 coefficients were stored in three low dynamic range textures. That means the shader needs just 4 texture taps to reconstruct the lighting, instead of 9.

Since lightmaps tend to be quite spatially coherent, they used block compressed formats for both: BC6HU for L0 (8 bits per pixel), and BC7 (8 bpp) or BC1 (4 bpp) for the 3xL1s. So that's just 20-32 bits per pixel of lightmap. A 4096x4096 resolution chunk of lightmap would cost you 40-64 MB of VRAM using that scheme, so it's quite doable. And the presentation slides show that you can get some beautiful visuals even with those aggressive reductions in raw data.

Importantly, they used this only for indirect lighting, and still evaluated direct lighting separately, which helps keep high frequency details that this approximation scheme crunches.

Comment: Thank you so much!  do you have experience with SH Lightmaps? I am planning to store both direct and indirect lighting. How many coefficients would you recommend if i want to store shadows?

Comment: I think you might want to switch to a different representation if you want to encode direct illumination and shadows too. You'll want a higher resolution grid of samples in that case, meaning storing extra coefficients gets even more costly, and all the extra texture taps in the shader will bog things down. But if you want to try it, start with these 4 and see if you need to trade up to 9 to get your desired look.

Comment: Or, the other route you could take is to switch to spherical harmonics light probes like in the example you're following, rather than a lightmap. Then you can look up the 9 coefficients from a small array rather than needing lots of texture bandwidth for it.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by that? You mean Placing probes and the fragment shader checks for nearby probes?

Comment: That would do it.